# How to detect drag operation at windows global scope?

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, mouse, hook

When I drag a folder at the edge of the screen in Windows XP, it becomes a toolbar containing the files in the folder.

How can windows detect there is a drag operation?

If I want to write an application to detect drag operation in system scope, how can I do this?

And another problem: how can I disable this Windows XP function, it is really annoying.

Comment: The desktop is handled by the shell process, explorer.exe. It's not happening at "Windows global scope".